# pod trunk push - error: Unexpected duplicate tasks

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, plist, podspec

I'm trying to create a new `cocoapod` which I built.

I've tried everything I know, playing with the build settings, playing with build phases and even starting a fresh new empty project - nothing helped, and I keep getting the following errors:

```
error: Unexpected duplicate tasks:
1) Target 'IdFramework' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/var/folders/j7/zvtf1r056n37blpr07lwpg_80000gr/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20210520-91577-hknniq-IdFramework/Pods/IdFramework/IdFramework/Info.plist' to '/Users/{username}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bmefgfaejhpjtdfjtbeehlmhmllt/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/IdFramework/IdFramework.framework/Info.plist'
2) Target 'IdFramework' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/var/folders/j7/zvtf1r056n37blpr07lwpg_80000gr/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20210520-91577-hknniq-IdFramework/Pods/IdFramework/IdFramework/Info.plist' to '/Users/{username}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bmefgfaejhpjtdfjtbeehlmhmllt/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/IdFramework/IdFramework.framework/Info.plist'
    
warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. (in target 'App' from project 'App')
warning: duplicate output file '/Users/{username}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bmefgfaejhpjtdfjtbeehlmhmllt/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/IdFramework/IdFramework.framework/Info.plist' on task: ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/{username}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bmefgfaejhpjtdfjtbeehlmhmllt/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/IdFramework/IdFramework.framework/Info.plist /var/folders/j7/zvtf1r056n37blpr07lwpg_80000gr/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20210520-91577-hknniq-IdFramework/Pods/Target Support Files/IdFramework/IdFramework-Info.plist (in target 'IdFramework' from project 'Pods')
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

I checked again and again, and there's nothing under `Copy Bundle Resources` - In fact the project gets compiled fine in `XCode`. I also tried to use the `Legacy Build System` - without success.

I'm using the latest version of `cocoapods`, with `XCode 12.1`.

What can possibly be the issue?